# Django, define field to be hidden in every form

Tags: django, forms, model, field

I have an abstract model `NamedEntry`. It has a field `body_raw` which contains the text as it was input by the user. The `body` field contains the converted (from markdown to html) cache for the `body_raw` field.

The `body` field should be hidden by default *everywhere*, on any form it might be used with. Is there something like `body = models.TextField(blank=True, hidden=True)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own Field, which will use widget with attribute `hidden`, for example:

```
class HiddenTextField(models.TextField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'widget': widgets.Textarea({'hidden': ''})}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(HiddenTextField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

And just replace `TextField` to `HiddenTextField` in your model(s)

Comment: I see what you did there.. Nifty xD Guess I just don't have the experience to come to such a solution. :)

Comment: PS: It did not work the way you posted it, for me. But instead using `kwargs.update(defaults)` made it! :)

Comment: @NiklasR, it should gives the same effect as `defaults.update(kwargs)` since the kwargs is empty. But if someone will pass a data to the `formfield`(for example by call or by overload this function in derived classes) - this information will lose. That's why I wrote `defaults.update(kwargs)`, but I don't know, why it didn't work with you.

Comment: Maybe because I checked it with the Django admin app. :)